# selenium InternetExporerDriver some elements click not consistently diring

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

So I have some tests in Selenium using the InternetExplorerDriver implementation of IWebDriver. Many of my objects respond to IWebElement.Click() well and consistently. I have anchors that click reliably for instance. I am writing some new stuff for clicking on a td. That is the element where the event handler is called says Mr Developer of the application under test.

The thing is it SEEMS to only fire click event and present the resultant hidden div when I am debugging the code but not when simply running it. There is not error thrown when the click is attempted.

I know that this is not a timing issue because there is something slow that is happening right before this test which allows the page to fully load.

Any other thoughts? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry folks for wasting your time. Operator error.